# How to Retrieve images from gallery and store in SQLite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

> Hey i am new in android application development.i currently develop
>   application, in some phase of that application deal with the image
>   store , retrieve and delete
>
> how can i store whole image in android ? and how can i retrieve more
>   than one images which i uploaded in SQLite wants in gallery view?
>
> please give me some guidance or link of blogs which deal with such
>   image processing in android

Comment: Solution may vary depending on your image amount, and type. If you are storing a lot of medium to large images, you will use external storage. As for small images, such as thumbnails, you can store it in database using blob fields. Second solution offers fully private access to the images, while for first solution, images are physical files and will appear in galleries, you may however place a .nomedia file to prevent this.

Comment: i fully clear with concept of storing and how to deal but how to implement in my case .?

Answer (score 1):

If u are dealing with images copy the image to separate folder and store the path in database OR store the image bytearray in db if size of image is small.

Comment: i want to store image in byte array form. so can you please give me way for storing and display in gallery view on retrieve back..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class ImageConvertScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  Button img_byte,byte_img;
  ImageView image;
  TextView value;
  public ByteArrayOutputStream bos;
  public Bitmap bm;
  public byte[] bitmapdata;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nextr);       
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_convert); 
        value=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.convert_txt); 
        img_byte =(Button)findViewById(R.id.img_byte);
        byte_img =(Button)findViewById(R.id.byte_img);
        img_byte.setOnClickListener(this);
        byte_img.setOnClickListener(this);

      String imgName = "ic_launcher";
      String  KEY_IMG = "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20121021_150153.jpg";

      File f =  new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), KEY_IMG);
      String path =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/image4.png";
       //bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
       bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),getResId(imgName, R.drawable.class));       
       bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
       bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20 , bos);


    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
  if (v == img_byte) { 
   bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
      Log.w("Image Conversion", String.valueOf(bitmapdata.length));
      String converted_txt=""; 
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ""+bitmapdata.length,1).show();
         for (int i = 0; i < bitmapdata.length; i++) { 
       Log.w("Image Conversion", String.valueOf(bitmapdata[i]));
          converted_txt=converted_txt+bitmapdata[i]; 
         } 
         saveImageOnSDCard1("testingImg",bitmapdata);
         value.setText(converted_txt);
         value.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

  } else if (v==byte_img){
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata , 0, bitmapdata .length);
        image.setImageBitmap(bm);
        image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        value.setText("");
        value.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Log.w("Image Conversion", "converted");

  }
    }
    public int getResId(String variableName, Class<?> c) {
        Field field = null;
        int resId = 0;
        try {
            field = c.getField(variableName);
            try {
                resId = field.getInt(null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resId;
    }
    public static void saveImageOnSDCard1(String imageName, byte[] data) {

        File file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/isus/");
        if (!file1.exists()) {
            boolean isCreated = file1.mkdirs();
            Log.e("Directory Created", "Directory Created " + isCreated);
        }

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/isus/" + imageName + ".png");
        Log.i("path",""+file.getAbsolutePath().toString());
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        try {
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            fileOutputStream.write(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("err",""+e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                fileOutputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```